# Which article is correct?

Tags: grammar

What is correct:If you see him,give him the message.OR If you see him,give him a message.

Comment: What do you think? Why? In what context? How many messages are you implying?

Comment: i think interpreting from the question person wants to give a particular message

Comment: Then either one will do. If there were several messages, _the_ might be confusing out of context.

Comment: but the is often used when to single out from a group so for particular message why "the" cannot be used.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that last comment. It's too far from English.

Comment: Either, depending on whether you've given the person you're speaking to the message already.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more context (it appears the OP doesn't know more context either, based on comment discussion), it's hard to completely invalidate either usage.

So, I would say, if the person you are talking to already knows ***the message***, then, "If you see him, give him ***the*** message," is better.

Otherwise, it is better to use, "If you see him, give him ***a*** message," followed by telling the listener the message you are asking them to convey.

If there are multiple messages involved, use ***the messages*** for the first case, and ***these messages*** for the latter.